# Put a delay between the thread of a particular sample in a thread group executing using csv file

Tags: jmeter

Thread Group
 ---Sampler 1
 ---Sampler 2
 while_Loop
     ----csv data set config
     ----Sampler 3

I just wanted to delay each thread of Sampler 3. I have tried several methods which are available on net but could not do this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "delay"? There are following options:

1. Adding a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to the While Controller will create a delay of defined number of milliseconds **before** the Sampler 3
2. Adding a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the Sampler 3 will create a delay of the defined number of milliseconds **after** the Sampler 3
3. Adding a [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) to the Thread Group will slow down **all** the samplers in the Thread Group to the defined number of requests per second

Comment: Thanks for the answer "Delay" means the time delay. I have used all these methods but not working as expected (All threads of sampler_3 is getting triggered at the same time). I can see ramp-up time is overriding all the delay method.